# Laravel access custom methods on model with vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, model

I am currently trying to implement a liked feature in my social laravel project and i am using this design. The like table is a pivot for User and Post table, a many to many relationship.

```
public function likePost(Post $post)
{            
     Auth::user()->likes()->attach($post->id);
      return response (post::with('user','likes','comments.user')- 
      >orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get());

        }

 }

    /**
     * Unfavorite a particular post
    *
    * @param  Post $post
    * @return Response
    */
    public function unlikePost(Post $post)
    {
        Auth::user()->likes()->detach($post->id);
        return post::with('user','likes','comments.user')- 
        >orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();

    }
```

There is the code for the LikeController

After defining the relationship in the User Model, I created a method to check if the post has been liked in my Post model

```
  public function liked()
  {
    return (bool) Like::where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->where('post_id', $this->id)
    ->first();
  }
```

There is the code for the Post Model. This is supposed to check if the post was liked.

So i also set up a vue component that takes in two props

```
<like :post={{ $post->id }}
      :favorited={{ post.liked ? 'true' : 'false' }}>
</like>
```

So my major problem now is i am using the like as a child component how would i call the liked() method on the Vue instance, if it were blade it would have been

```
<like :post={{ $post->id }}
      :favorited={{ $post->liked() ? 'true' : 'false' }}>
</like>
```

how can i do that with vue??

Comment: Can you show me the logic of how you retrieve the post in the controller?

Comment: Route::get('/home/posts', function () {
  return response(App\post::with('user','likes','comments.user')
  ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
  ->get() );  
  
});